# Non-submodularity of sparse approximations to Gaussian posterior

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, approximate-inference, discrete-optimization

Imagine that we are doing approximate inference on a Gaussian mean, minimizing a variational objective that corresponds to the reverse KL divergence between a sparse approximate posterior computed on a subset of $M$ datapoints each with weight $\frac{N}{M}$, and the true posterior computed on the full dataset of $N$ observations.

Is the negative of this objective a submodular function (of the considered set of datapoints)?

My intuition is that this is not submodular: Imagine the case that we have two symmetric outliers (with respect to the observations' mean) that cancel each other's contribution to the sufficient statistic of the data. If we add one of the outliers to a dataset of inliers, we will get smaller gains compared to adding the outlier to a superset which also contains the other mirrored outlier.